# I Have a problem retrieving some null data from my DB?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get a specific value from my DB but I am getting some exception and I can't manage it, any suggestions?

I have already tried to use the `??` operator but still have the problem.

This is my line of code:

```
var Emp_Attendance_ID = db.Emplooyee_Attendance.Where(a => a.Employee_ID == item.Id).Max(p => p.Attendance_ID);
```

I am expecting an ID but all i get is the following exception:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized
>   value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query
>   must use a nullable type.

Comment: Include your Emplooyee_Attendance and item model in the question so we can see their properties.

Comment: did you try "?"

.Max(p => p?.Attendance_ID);

if no match - it will return NULL

Answer (score 0):

I would do a null check in a where and then get the matching items from the remaining elements if there are any.

```
var Emp_Attendance_ID = db.Emplooyee_Attendance
    .Where(a => a.Employee_ID != null)
    .Where(a => a.Employee_ID == item.Id)
    .Max(p => p.Attendance_ID);
```

let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: I have tried this solution but it throws another exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: @MohamedMounir It means the `Where` returns 0 elements, i.e. there's no match for your condition.

Comment: It essentially means that none of the Employee_ID's are different from null and equal to item.Id at the same time. So when you try to take the max of that you try to take the max of nothing and that throws the Sequence contains no elements exception.

Comment: I would strongly recommend moving the .ToList() to the end of the chain.

Comment: @Robert Yeah I see what you mean but IQueriable doesn't allow expression trees.
Instead I think a double where to ensure no cast exception is the best.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Where` condition doesn't match anything. Since you're looking for **IDs** (which I assume are integers), I suggest you check your models/database structure for missing constraints. Also, since you're looking for a `Max` result, I guess there might be many, but if eventually that's not the case, you might want to consider using `SingleOrDefault(...)` or `FirstOrDefault(...)` instead of `Where(...).Max(...)`. Anyway, to manage the problem with your code as of now, you could either check if there's any match before doing something, e.g.

```
    if (db.Emplooyee_Attendance.Any(a => a.Employee_ID == item.Id))
    {
       var Emp_Attendance_ID = db.Emplooyee_Attendance.Where(a => a.Employee_ID == item.Id)
                                                      .Max(p => p.Attendance_ID);
       // Rest of your code...
    }
    else
       // Do something different?
```

or you could assign the result of the `Where` to a variable and check on that, since it's an `IEnumerable`, e.g.

```
IEnumerable<int> result = db.Emplooyee_Attendance.Where(a => a.Employee_ID == item.Id);
if (result.Count() > 0)
{
   int Emp_Attendance_ID = result.Max(p => p.Attendance_ID);
   // Rest of your code...
}
else
   // Do something different?
```